# Could not access the SSO database During biztalk runtime Configuration

Tags: sql-server-2012, single-sign-on, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm trying to test a migration of moving a BizTalk SQL Server from one server to another. Here are the details.

Currently it was all on a single server in a dev environment, BizTalk SQL, SSO and BizTalk runtime all on one server. It is a Windows 2008 R2 server with SQL Server 2008 R2.

What I want to do is split out the SSO Master secret server and BizTalk databases to a Windows Server 2012/SQL Server 2012 setup. So far I got SSO all setup on the new SQL server. I configured just the SSO portion on that server and all went well.

I then unconfigured the existing BizTalk Runtime and then went to configure again, using the new Windows/SQL Server/SSO in the configuration process.

All goes well up to the point where it tries to configure the BizTalk runtime. That being said all the database are created, SSODB, BizTalkMessageBoxDb, all of them. But when it goes to configure BizTalk Runtime, it hangs for a while and several of the following errors show up in both of the Server's logs:

```
Could not access the SSO database. If this condition persists, the SSO service will go offline.
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding..
SQL Error code: 0xFFFFFFFE
```

It shows up in the SQL/SSO servers logs first, then the Runtime server a few seconds later. Eventually the configuration times out and fails. I believe it's permissions related, but I can't seem to figure out what it would be.

Questions:

- what permissions do I need to review?
- would the fact that the new server is Windows 2012/SQL 2012 while the runtime server is Windows 2008 be an issue?
- is there any way I can get more details on this error?

Edit to add both DTCPing and DTCTester pass with flying colours and I can connect to SQL via SSMS from the server. Firewall has been completely disabled for now in order to eliminate that as well.

Comment: Does SSO configure successfully on it's own?  Try doing one option at a time.

Comment: It does. SSO and Group successfully finish configuring. Just the BizTalk Runtime fails. Then I try to do it on it's own after and it just keeps failing...very slowly I might add.

Answer (score 0):

How were your service accounts configured in the first environment? Typically a single DEV environment with everything on one box can be done by using a local account on that server. If you now split out your SSO onto another server (it doesn't matter if it's W2K12 instead of W2K8), you are going to have to switch your service account(s) and groups for BizTalk to Domain accounts.

In a multicomputer environment, BizTalk Server supports only domain groups and domain service accounts. Domain groups include Domain Local groups (not recommended), Global groups, and Universal groups. Built-in accounts such as NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, and Everyone are not supported if you want to configure BTS in a multicomputer environment.

Make sure your SSO is running as a domain account, and a member of an SSO Administrators domain group - and ensure this domain account/group combo is configured for the SSO system on the SQL server (instead of local accounts):

[image: Configure SSO on SQL with Domain Accounts and Domain Groups]

After that the SSO system you join from the BizTalk Server before configuring the runtime on BizTalk Server usually needs to be configured with the same domain service account for SSO:

[image: Join SSO System from BTS with Domain Account]